# Как сделать разделители меню серыми?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Подскажите как сделать разделители меню серыми.
Вот как сейчас:
[image: Пример как не надо]
Вот как необходимо сделать:
[image: Пример как надо]
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Вы хотите серые разделители в меню самой Intellij IDEA?

Comment: Нет, это меню вызывается нажатием "Правой кнопки мыши"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это неактивные элементы меню. Можна сасмому попробовать создать тему в Intellij IDEA. Поищи среди кастомных тем. [Color Themes](http://color-themes.com/?view=index)